# How to change sections numbering in starred chapter without changing document class?

Tags: sections-paragraphs, starred-version

My report starts with a starred chapter "Introduction". My  problem is with sections' numbers. They all start with 0, so I get 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 as shown below. I need to delete zeros and keep only 1,2 and 3 without changing the document class to article. How can I do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after `\chapter*{Introduction Générale}`, issue

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Then, immediately after your second `\chapter{<title>}`, issue

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

This should work regardless of the document class you're using.